# Sudoku: Making a method that reads a file and put every sudoku into and list of 2 dimensional arrays. Cant seem to be able to read the file

Tags: java

My program is using javafx to make a Sudoku Solution Checker. I have currently a Button in javafx start method that allows me to open the directory and select a `.txt` file. The file contains bunch of solutions to 9 x 9 sudoku puzzles. I keep getting an exception for my code saying its coming from my readSolutions method.

My javafx start method looks like this:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    window = primaryStage;
    
    //Scene
        //Instruction for loading
        //Load button
        //File name as a label = empty at first
        //Label for instructions "after selecting a file click Check 
        //Check Sudoku Solution Button
        //Check Next Sudoku Solution Button
    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    pane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    pane.setHgap(5);
    pane.setVgap(5);
    
    Label fileSelection = new Label("Select Sudoku .TXT File");
    Button load = new Button("Load File");
    Label selectedFile = new Label();
    Label comment = new Label("After selecting a File click NEXT button below");
    Label instruction = new Label("Click Next button below to check next Sudoku");
    Button next = new Button("Next");
    Label validation = new Label();
    //next.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(checking));
    load.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            
            //Open directory from existing directory
            if(file != null){
                File existDirectory = file.getParentFile();
                fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(existDirectory);
            }

            //Set extension filter
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TEXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
            
            //Show open file dialog
            file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            
            selectedFile.setText(file.getPath());
            

            //checking button ADD FUNCTION TO THIS
            //check.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(checking));
            
            //layout for checking scene
            try {
                grids = readSolutions(file);
                if (grids.size() >  0) {
                    int[][] currentGrid = grids.remove(0);
                    for( int i = 0; i <9 ; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                            TextField text = new TextField();
                            text.setText(String.valueOf(currentGrid[j][i]));
                            pane.add(text, j, i);
                            validation.setText(isValid(currentGrid) ? "Correct" : "Incorrect");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
                validation.setText("File not found try again");
            }
            
            
        }
    });
    
    //layout for loading scene;
    BorderPane rootPane = new BorderPane();
    VBox layout1 = new VBox(5);
    layout1.getChildren().addAll(fileSelection, load, selectedFile, comment, instruction, next, validation);
    //rootPane.getChildren().addAll(pane, layout1);
    rootPane.setLeft(pane);
    rootPane.setRight(layout1);
    
    Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 700, 350);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.setTitle("Check Sudoku Solution");
    window.show();
}
```

The read solutions method looks like this:

```
public List<int[][]> readSolutions(File file) throws FileNotFoundException{
    
    StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    
    bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getPath()));
        
    String text;
    try {
        while ((text = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(text);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    text = stringBuffer.toString();
    //text.replaceAll("\\s", "");       
    String[] intString = text.split(" ");
    int[] nums = new int[intString.length];
    for(int k = 0; k < nums.length; k++) {
        nums[k] = Integer.parseInt(intString[k]);
    }
    
    
    List<Integer> all = new ArrayList<Integer>(nums.length);
    for (int j : nums) {
        all.add(j);
    }
    
    
    List<int[][]> grids = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
    int[][] currentGrid = new int[9][9];
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++) {
        currentGrid[row][col] =  all.get(i);
        col++;
        if (i % 9 == 0) {
            row++;
            col = 0;
        }
        if (i % 81 == 0) {
            grids.add(currentGrid);
            row = 0;
            currentGrid = new int[9][9];
        }
    }
    return grids;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace too?

Comment: Your code assumes the only exception that could come from `readSolutions()` is a file not found exception.  You're using [Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)), though, which will throw an exception if the input is not an integer.  Most likely you have bad input in your file that you were not expecting, like a blank string or possibly an actual string that isn't a number.